# Customizing list items with SVG icons

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to customize the bullet points of an unordered list in an html with icons I pulled off of some websites. Here's the SVG code for the first icon, stored in `home.svg`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
    stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
    class="feather feather-home">
    <path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path>
    <polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline>
</svg>
```

And the SVG code for the second icon stored in `linkedin.svg`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="blue"
  class="bi bi-linkedin" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path
    d="M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4" />
</svg>
```

In the html document, I declare a simple unordered list with list items having different classes:

And in my `styles.css` file I attach each of those classes to either `home.svg` or `linkedin.svg`:

```css
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.first::before
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    content: url('home.svg');
}

li.second::before
{
    display: inline-block
    width: 16px;
    content: url('linkedin.svg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="first">First item</li>
        <li class="second">Second item</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to work and I get the following result:

[image]

This looks allright but as you can probably see the sizes of the two icons are different, and they also seem to be offset from the text content of the list item.

How can I homogenize their sizes and ensure they are better aligned with the text?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.first::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");    
}

li.second::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='blue' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">First item</li>
  <li class="second">Second item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't turn this into a snippet because it depends on external SVG files. Isn't the code I provided sufficiently minimal and reproducible?

Comment: My mistake, CSS has been added to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Use a flexbox on the list items to control the gap between the icon and the text, and to align them vertically.

Use a flexbox on the pseudo-elements containing the icons as well, to keep the icons centered within the pseudo-element.

You can play around with the width and height attributes inside each SVG so that the end result is that appear at the same size. This is a bit of a hack, though. I’d prefer to decide on my optimum size, then edit the SVG icons in an SVG editor so that they all match that size. Or better still, find an icon pack which has been designed as a group, so that all icons have the same size and style, and which contains all the icons you need.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

li::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");    
}

li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='blue' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there perhaps an alternative way which doesn't involve using a flexbox? I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible...

Comment: The simplest possible solution is to reference your images in the HTML: `<li><img src="home.svg"> First item</li>`. That should provide better styling flexibility than using pseudo-elements. Alternatively, editing your SVGs to all be the same size (or choosing SVGs which are already the same size) should help a lot.

Comment: But if you are not comfortable with flexbox, you really need to spend a bit of time [experimenting with it](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's wonderful and simple, you just need to get the hang of it, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Placing svgs via `content` property will respect intrinsic dimensions – if defined by `width` and `height` in the dataURL.

Here's an exaggerated example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.first::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'><path d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z' /><polyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22' /></svg>");    
}

li.second::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='blue' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M0 1.1c0-.6.5-1.1 1.2-1.1h13.6c.7 0 1.2.5 1.2 1.1v13.8c0 .6-.5 1.1-1.2 1.1h-13.6c-.7 0-1.2-.5-1.2-1.1zm4.9 12.3v-7.2h-2.4v7.2h2.4m-1.2-8.2c.9 0 1.4-.6 1.4-1.3s-.5-1.2-1.3-1.2-1.4.5-1.4 1.2.5 1.3 1.3 1.3zm5 8.2v-4c0-.3 0-.5 0-.6.2-.5.6-.9 1.3-.9s1.2.7 1.2 1.6v3.9h2.4v-4.1c0-2.3-1.2-3.3-2.8-3.3-1.3 0-1.8.7-2.1 1.2h-.1a5.5 5.5 0 01.1 0v-1h-2.4c0 .6 0 7.2 0 7.2h2.4' /></svg>");    
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="first">First item</li>
        <li class="second">Second item</li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see the first icon is rendered at 100x100 px, although the pseudo element's width is defined as 16px.

You can easily prevent this by **stripping the width and height attributes** from your dataURL embedded svg like so

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right:0.5em;
}


li.first::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'><path d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z' /><polyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22' /></svg>");
}

li.second::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%230000ff' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M0 1.1c0-.6.5-1.1 1.2-1.1h13.6c.7 0 1.2.5 1.2 1.1v13.8c0 .6-.5 1.1-1.2 1.1h-13.6c-.7 0-1.2-.5-1.2-1.1zm4.9 12.3v-7.2h-2.4v7.2h2.4m-1.2-8.2c.9 0 1.4-.6 1.4-1.3s-.5-1.2-1.3-1.2-1.4.5-1.4 1.2.5 1.3 1.3 1.3zm5 8.2v-4c0-.3 0-.5 0-.6.2-.5.6-.9 1.3-.9s1.2.7 1.2 1.6v3.9h2.4v-4.1c0-2.3-1.2-3.3-2.8-3.3-1.3 0-1.8.7-2.1 1.2h-.1a5.5 5.5 0 01.1 0v-1h-2.4c0 .6 0 7.2 0 7.2h2.4' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">First item</li>
  <li class="second">Second item</li>
</ul>
```

However, make sure all icons' viewBox values are appropriate.

Credits to **Danny '365CSI' Engelman's** comments in other posts pointing out, modern browsers can handle less escaped/URLencoded svg markup in DataURLs: replacing double with single quotes for attribute values and `%23` with `#` is usually enough. This is quite handy to write more readable css code.

Comment: I tried this with urls to physical files on my hard drive instead of dataURLs but it didn't seem to work... the icons still had different sizes despite stripping the `width` and `height` attributes

Comment: Do these external svgs have appropriate viewboxes? Please share an example of one of these files that's not working properly

Comment: I've provided the code to the files in the OP.... you can just copy that code into appropriately named files and then strip the `width` and `height` attributes

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works with external svgs just as well. See [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vTt46Ww8lEfdq4On?open=index.html&preview)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which doesn't involve the use of flexbox and still allows me to tweak the size and padding of the marker icons is as follows:

```css
ul
{
padding: 0;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 20px;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='blue' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Granted, this is probably a hack or misuse of `background-image` but it will do for now.